# Make collapsible Div align on right instead of left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the exact code in this JS fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9Le8X/2/

However, I want that collapsible div to function like this on the right side instead of the left, specifically, on first load I only want the orange square to be shown on the right side. When clicked the panel content pulls out from the right. I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div id="slide-panel">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="opener"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></a>
    Panel Content
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slide-panel {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#eee;
    margin-left:-300px;
}
#opener {
    float:right;
    margin:-10px -50px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

JS

```
$('#opener').on('click', function() {       
        var panel = $('#slide-panel');
        if (panel.hasClass("visible")) {
            panel.removeClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'-300px'});
        } else {
            panel.addClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'0px'});
        }   
        return false;   
    });
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is you updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/ng0r3nqy/

You should separate the content from the hamburger.

```
$('#opener').on('click', function() {       
    var panel = $('#slide-panel');
    if (panel.hasClass("visible")) {
        panel.removeClass('visible').animate({'left':'-300px'});
    } else {
        panel.addClass('visible').animate({'left':'0px'});
    }   
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: Hiya! Thanks. Not quite sure that Fiddle is working like I want right now. On first load I only want the orange square to be shown on the right side. When clicked the panel content pulls out from the right. Right now, your panel content isn't hidden.

Comment: Hi, thank you! That's much better. Now one last thing. I am trying to have this work "on top" of my content. So I tried setting the position: absolute and Z-index: 1000. It works, but the slide-panel is no longer sitting on the right edge of the screen. It floats closer to the left. What can I do?

Comment: UPDATE: I added a surrounding DIV to the slide-panel with `position:absolute; right:0;` inside. With some other minor css adjusting that did the trick :)